# this.Close() not killing thread created by observer NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, caliburn.micro

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm having the following problem: I have a WPF application that executes an infinite task which performs some pretty expensive background operations. Those operations can occasionally change a value and it has to be updated in the UI. The operations need to run in a thread different than the UI thread, since they could lock the UI. So, I'm trying to use the System.Reactive library and it's actually working pretty well... but, when I try to close the application by using a custom close button that executes the `this.Close();` method, the app is not being closed.

My observable looks something like this:

```
internal IObservable<string> DoBackgroundOperations(string param) {

    return Observable.Create<string>(o => {
        NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule(() => {
            for (;;) {
                param = // some operations that change the param

                // when the param has been changed, I send the new value to the subscribers
                o.OnNext(param);
            }
        });

        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

Then I'm subscribing to it and changing the value I need to update in the UI:

```
sevice.DoBackgroundOperations(param).Subscribe(newVal => Data = newVal);
```

As I said before, I'm receiving the updated values when they come and it's working well, but when the click event of the close button is triggered, the UI window "disappears" but the application itself is never being closed. I think the thread created by the observable is keeping the app alive.

So, my question is: how can I properly close the app and prevent the thread from keeping it alive?

Thanks!

### Edit

I'm using caliburn.micro for implementing the MVVM pattern. I'm doing the subscription in one of my ViewModel classes. I don't think it matters, but just in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ever return `Disposable.Empty`. You're forced to do that because your code doesn't have a natural disposable in turn because you create an infinite loop.

Get rid of the infinite loop and you can make the whole problem go away.

You could solve this simply by this:

```
internal IObservable<string> DoBackgroundOperations(string param)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Generate(
                0,
                x => true,
                x => x + 1,
                x => /* some operations that change the param */,
                Scheduler.Default);
}
```

I purposely chose `Scheduler.Default` because `Scheduler.NewThread` has been deprecated.

Had you provided the code for `// some operations that change the param` I could have given you working code.

Now, to close your app cleanly you should dispose of any subscriptions you create, but at least you'd no longer be tying up a thread in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The "operations" are actually, reading and analyzing a few files in the file system. Depending of the content of those files, the observer could send the new param to the ViewModel so it can update the UI.

Comment: For simplicity reasons, we could always simplify it to a `Thread.Sleep(3000); o.onNext("newParam");`.

Comment: `Observable.Generate` is very powerful. It's one to learn and use instead of `Observable.Create` where possible.